# Opening a file that has colons in the filename with Java (displayed as slashes in MacOs Finder)

Tags: java, file, bro, zeek

**This issue is for Linux/Mac; I don't even think the files could exist with slashes if they were unzipped onto a Windows box.**

Hi, I have a requirement to open log files which were output by the popular BRO IDS system.  The files are read only and I need to process their contents without changing the filenames.

For some reason the Bro filenames are in this format: "conn.19/00/00-22/00/00.log". (also .gz versions of this, with slashes)  I tried running the latest instance of Bro on my Mac with default settings and it produced log files with the same forward slash pattern, so this was a conscious decision someone else made, which I will have to work around.

In loading a file as a Java unit test, either through

`File("conn.19/00/00-22/00/00.log")`

or by URL

`getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("conn.19/00/00-22/00/00.log")`

I get the expected problem of the forward slash being interpreted as a non-existing directory.

**I've found a bunch of other downvoted questions about slashes in filenames, mostly by people that wanted to create such problems.  I'm looking for a solution to deal with these bad filenames, within Java.

If I can get the file data to an InputStream, I'll be golden.

**Update 1:  This works better as an update than as a comment, since it changes the nature of the problem.**

I discovered that in MacOS, and possibly Linux, the Finder GUI application shows the filenames with forward slashes, like this:

[image: Bro Log File in MacOS Finder]

However in the terminal I see this:

[image: Bro Log File in terminal]

Finally, the File.list() command also interprets it this way:

[image]

So the solution is to use the colon ':' character when reading in the file.  Turns out this is one heck of a rabbit hole which may involve encoding the ':' to "%3a" or double encoding to "%253a".  Neither of those have worked yet in my permutations.

See:
[JDK-7037120 : Identity violation in java.net.URI](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7037120)

[Accessing an archive file with a colon in its file name throws a NullPointerException or an AssertionError](https://java.net/projects/truezip/lists/issues/archive/2011-04/message/48)

Comment: `conn.19\/00\/00-22\/00\/00.log`

Comment: That's a very strange format, I was convinced you can't have `/` in filename on Unix/Linux under any circumstances because filesystem won't allow it

Comment: I agree with @Luke - the `/` is supposed to be reserved for a directory separator.  Are you *sure* the character is an actual ASCII `/` and not something else?

Comment: Andrew you're correct, MacOS Finder was showing the colons as forward slashes in the GUI.  Having colons seems to present its own problems.

Comment: They're in that format because it is a valid format and is the default for the tool.